# Update CSS of Pseudo Element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

I've spotted a number of posts stating that I can't manipulate a Pseudo Element with jQuery so I'm looking for a workaround?

I'm looking to run a a/b split test in Optimizely on our site search bar. 
The design of the current search bar has css that creates the search icon using  the ::before Pseudo element to place a glyph-icon as a button to start the search.

As my test I wanted to change the colour of this icon. Optimizely allows you to use jQuery to target elements and make these types of changes.

The current css looks like this:

```
.header .form-search button:before, .header .form-search .search- button:before {
content: "\f002";
font-family: "polar-icons";
color: #237cb2;
font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

This was the jQuery I was attempting to implement but it didn't work:

```
$(".search-button::before").css({'color':'#E93826'});
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just toggle a class? Because you cannot target pseudo elements using js/jquery   `.search- button:before.sexyClass {color: #E93826; }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Comment: @SrinivasPai OP doesn't want to change content but style

Comment: Sorry, it should be: `.search-button.sexyClass:before {color: #E93826; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('head').append('<style>.search-button::before{color:#E93826 !important}</style>');
```